# sonarqube 5.6 api to delete mysql database artifact entry and clean up all associated tables

Tags: mysql, git, sonarqube

We are changing our continuous delivery system, which interacts with git, to allow all pull requests on branches to do sonarqube analysis.
If we use the "-Dsonar.branch=some_branch_name" in the mvn sonar:sonar command I believe this will create a new mysql database entry for the project.
As there may be hundreds of these done per week, if not per day, I would like to automate the cleanup of these branch entries from the mysql database when git indicates a merge or deletion of the branch instead of using the manual bulk delete feature of the GUI.
Is there, or is there in the planning, an API which I could provide the branch information (index or artifactID) to, when the branch is finally merged or deleted, so the mysql database could be cleaned up when our continuous delivery system is informed by git of this condition?

Answer (score 1):

In general, there's a Web Service for each action you can perform through the UI. In this case, what you want is either the `delete` or `bulk_delete` [service](https://sonarqube.com/web_api/api/projects).

To use either of these services, you need the project guids. The `api/projects/index` service should help you find them.

You'll also need a [token](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/User+Token) from a [properly-permissioned](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Authorization) (Global Admin for bulk delete, project admin - on that project - for delete) user. Send the token as the login/user value and leave the password blank. As mentioned in the comments (thanks Nicolas!) the documentation on that is [here](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/DEV/Web+API#WebAPI-UserToken).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I still have not figured out though what the authorization header should look like. I have generated a admin user token but I have not been able to see how to use this in conjunction to the post api/projects/delete. I have successfully obtained the project using a GET and api/projects/index?key=49861, but again I have not found an example of how I can use the token to authenticate for the POST to delete. Any help/examples would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Use the token as username and set the password as empty (see [related documentation](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/DEV/Web+API#WebAPI-UserToken))

Comment: @Nicholas Thanks for the feedback. This appears to have corrected this issue, however I am still not able to delete a project as I don't have the right id or key. My GET using an index number shows data for the projects id, k, nm, sc, and qu, but I do not see the correct data (per the example) to use for  id or key. Where do I go to get the right information to use as the id or key? I can send screen shots if you would like.

Comment: I found how I can get the key appropriately to do what I need with it. No further response needed. Thanks for all your help.